# Answer draft does not remember Community Wiki status

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki, draft

When you write an answer but don't post it yet, the system will save it as a draft (just like with questions). For questions, the draft functionality remembers more than just the body: title and tags are saved too. For answers, the Community Wiki checkbox is not remembered; it's always unchecked when you return to the draft. Could this be added as well?